# How to make a looped image background in React Native with Animated

Tags: react-native

I originally used `setInterval()` to make a looped image background by having two images that one starts at `x:0` and another starts at `x: imageWidth`, then update them in the following way:

```
  _updateBackgroundImage = () => {
    this.setState({
      background1Left: this.state.background1Left > (-this.backgroundImageWidth) ? this.state.background1Left-3 : this.backgroundImageWidth,
      background2Left: this.state.background2Left > (-this.backgroundImageWidth) ? this.state.background2Left-3 : this.backgroundImageWidth,
    })
  }
```

It worked just fine but `setInterval()` was causing conflicts with another component from an online library, so I switched to using `Animated` API and have the following code:

```
this.translateValue = new Animated.Value(0)

  translate() {
    this.translateValue.setValue(0)
    Animated.timing(
      this.translateValue,
      {
        toValue: 1,
        duration: 14000,
        easing: Easing.linear
      }
    ).start(()=>this.translate())
  }
```

> ```
> const translateBackgroundImage1 = this.translateValue.interpolate({
>   inputRange: [0, 1],
>   outputRange: [0, -this.backgroundImageWidth]
> })
> const translateBackgroundImage2 = this.translateValue.interpolate({
>   inputRange: [0, 1],
>   outputRange: [this.backgroundImageWidth, -this.backgroundImageWidth]
> })
>
>
> return (
>   <View style={{flex:1}}>
>
>    <Animated.Image
>       style={{
>         flex: 1,
>         position: 'absolute',
>         left: translateBackgroundImage1,
>          }}
>       resizeMode={Image.resizeMode.cover}
>       source={this.backgroundImage}
>     />
>     <Animated.Image
>       style={{
>         flex: 1,
>         position: 'absolute',
>         left: translateBackgroundImage2,
>          }}
>       resizeMode={Image.resizeMode.cover}
>       source={this.backgroundImage}
>     />
> ```

To apply the same logic I used for `setInterval()` I would have `translateBackgroundImage1` to start at `x:0` in the first loop and then starts at `x: ImageWidth`

I'm not sure how to implement this with `Animated`

Comment: did u find the solution  ?

Comment: @NabeelK Yes I did. I will post my solution below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually found a solution. It's not very clean but works.

I essentially have two `Animated.image` loaded from the same image. Then I have a `translateValue1`, which controls the left position of the first image. Then based on `translateValue1`, we have `translateValue2` that has an `offset` of the `imagewidth`. `translateValue2` controls the left position of the second image.

When the first image about to exit from the screen, it will go to the far right of the screen, and at the same time the second image will be moved to the front of the first image, so we need to change the `offset` to `-imagewidth`. Therefore there's a `setState` method in each of the two animation functions.

Inside the constructor I have these variables:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.backgroundImage = require('../assets/images/graidenttPastel.jpg'); 
    this.backgroundImageWidth = resolveAssetSource(this.backgroundImage).width;
    this.translateXValue1 = new Animated.Value(-1);
    this.translateXValue2 = new Animated.Value(0);
    this.animationLength = 20000;

    this.state = {
      translateXValue2Offset: this.backgroundImageWidth,
      stopAnimation: false,
    }
```

Then I have these two functions, each controls half of the loop:

```
  translateXFirstHalfLoop() {
    this.translateXValue1.setValue(-1);
    this.setState({translateXValue2Offset: this.backgroundImageWidth});
    this.firstHalfLoop = Animated.timing(
      this.translateXValue1,
      {
        toValue: -this.backgroundImageWidth,
        duration: this.animationLength/2,
        easing: Easing.linear
      }
    ).start(() => {
      if(this.state.stopAnimation === false) {
        this.translateXSecondHalfLoop()
      }
    })
  }


  translateXSecondHalfLoop() {
    this.translateXValue1.setValue(this.backgroundImageWidth);
    this.setState({translateXValue2Offset: -this.backgroundImageWidth});
    this.secondHalfLoop = Animated.timing(
      this.translateXValue1,
      {
        toValue: 0,
        duration: this.animationLength/2,
        easing: Easing.linear
      }
    ).start(() => {
      if(this.state.stopAnimation === false) {
        this.translateXFirstHalfLoop()
      }
    })
  }
```

Finally in the `render()` method, I have two `Animated.Image` like below:

```
  render() {
    this.translateXValue2 = Animated.add(this.translateXValue1, this.state.translateXValue2Offset);

    return (
      <SafeAreaView
        style={[{backgroundColor: THEME_COLOR, flex: 1}]}
        forceInset={{ bottom: 'never' }}>
        <Animated.Image
          style={{
            position: 'absolute',
            left: this.translateXValue1,
             }}
          resizestate={Image.resizeMode.cover}
          source={this.backgroundImage}
        />
        <Animated.Image
          style={{
            position: 'absolute',
            left: this.translateXValue2,
             }}
          resizestate={Image.resizeMode.cover}
          source={this.backgroundImage}
        />
        <View style={{flex:1}}>

          {this._renderScreenContent()}

        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
```

Since each half loop function calls the other, we need to stop them before this component is unmounted, so we have this additional step below:

```
//clean up animation first
this.setState({stopAnimation: true}, () => {
  this.props.navigation.goBack()
})
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to animate an `ImageBackground`, try

```
var AnimatedImage = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(ImageBackground)
```